# nginx sometimes is stopping

Tags: nginx, debian, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

My nginx on virtual machine is stopping and I can't figure out the reason.

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

returns

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Also there are some logs:

```
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
```

logs:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-05-20 12:26:38 UTC; 2h 34min ago
  Process: 25083 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25126 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25123 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6426 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 20 12:26:37 sl-code nginx[25126]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 12:26:37 sl-code nginx[25126]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code nginx[25126]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code nginx[25126]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code nginx[25126]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code nginx[25126]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 12:26:38 sl-code systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

error logs:
sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2020/04/17 03:58:54 [notice] 18191#18191: signal process started
2020/04/17 03:58:54 [error] 18191#18191: invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
2020/04/17 03:58:59 [notice] 18195#18195: signal process started
2020/04/17 03:59:05 [emerg] 18238#18238: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/04/17 03:59:05 [emerg] 18238#18238: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/04/17 03:59:05 [emerg] 18238#18238: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/04/17 03:59:05 [emerg] 18238#18238: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/04/17 03:59:05 [emerg] 18238#18238: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/04/17 03:59:05 [emerg] 18238#18238: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

Comment: it looks like there is some competition on the 80 and 443 ports. Is there any other web server in the VM or in the vm HOST (your pc) ? could also be skype on your host (not the vm) as it is using port 80 by default (you can change that), in case you also are mapping VM port to your host port.

Comment: The problem is still present. 
This is a digitalocean droplet and i did not install any other web servers on it.

Comment: Tried to check who is using port 80 and 443 and result is empty. It looks like some job process is killing the nginx process

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you have another webserver running. Try and stop all of the other webserver processes and restart nginx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you you have another program bound to ports 80 and 443. Since you're on ubuntu running `sudo lsof -i` should help you figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

This may be because some other services are using the same port (80 and 443).

To identify it use

```
sudo lsof -i
```

For filtering the result of above code for ports  80 and 443 use

```
sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
```

```
sudo lsof -i :443 | grep LISTEN
```

to find out which services are using your ports 80 and 443.

**Solution 2:**

Check whether you have installed other web servers like `apache`.

If it is installed please remove it and restart `nginx`
using

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

**Solution 3:**

Check if `nginx` is using much amount of RAM.

The OS will stop the service if it is using the RAM which cannot be handled by the system

Comment: user@machine:~$ sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
nginx   21374     root              6u  IPv4 442296      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   21374     root              7u  IPv6 442297      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   21375     www-data    6u  IPv4 442296      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   21375     www-data    7u  IPv6 442297      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Comment: Did you try that after nginx stopped.

Comment: Yeah. Just stopped again. Tried to run sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN and no results

Comment: Also tried to add more RAM and had no effect. Btw, there is no apache of other server installed.

Comment: Sometime if the nginx is running any scripts like infinite loop the program will use much amount of RAM. So the system will stop the service. Did you check for scripts like that?

Answer (score 0):

You might have another web service running along with the Nginx which is clashing. You can inspect that by running `sudo lsof -i`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have a wrong configuration file in **sites-enabled**. you have to find that file manually and delete that file and then

```
sudo service Nginx restart
```

I hope this will work for you